# AttributeError when trying to build Pandas docs

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to build the Pandas docs using `python make.py html` as described in the [Contributing to Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/contributing.html#building-the-documentation) guide.

But I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/some_user/pandas/pandas/tseries/tools.py", line 458, in <module>
    DateParseError = tslib.DateParseError
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DateParseError'
```

I've installed all the optional dependencies (I think) and my `pd.show_versions()` looks like this:

```
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 2.7.10.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Linux
OS-release: 3.13.0-37-generic
machine: x86_64
processor: x86_64
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_GB.UTF-8

pandas: 0.16.2
nose: 1.3.7
Cython: 0.23
numpy: 1.9.2
scipy: 0.16.0
statsmodels: 0.6.1
IPython: 4.0.0
sphinx: 1.3.1
patsy: 0.4.0
dateutil: 2.4.2
pytz: 2015.4
bottleneck: 1.0.0
tables: None
numexpr: 2.4.3
matplotlib: 1.4.3
openpyxl: 2.0.2
xlrd: 0.9.4
xlwt: 1.0.0
xlsxwriter: 0.7.3
lxml: 3.4.4
bs4: None
html5lib: 0.999
httplib2: None
apiclient: None
sqlalchemy: 1.0.8
pymysql: 0.6.6.None
psycopg2: 2.6 (dt dec pq3 ext)
```

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: My bad. I had to `source deactivate` my conda development environment, then the docs building proceeded as normal.